# Creating a "Event" in MySQL throu JAVA.JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Hello i'm having trouble creating a MySQL "Event" through JAVA.JDBC. Here's the code:

```
public void skapaAuktionsEvent(String produktnamn, String slutdatum) throws SQLException{

    String sql = "CREATE EVENT "+ produktnamn +" ON SCHEDULE AT '"+ slutdatum +"' DO UPDATE Auktion SET AvslutadAuktion = 1 WHERE produktnamn = "+ produktnamn;

    System.out.println("Skapar event");


    PreparedStatement stm = conn.prepareStatement("CREATE EVENT ? ON SCHEDULE AT ? DO UPDATE Auktion SET AvslutadAuktion = 1 WHERE produktnamn = ?",
            ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    stm.setString(1, produktnamn);
    stm.setString(2, slutdatum);
    stm.setString(3, produktnamn);

    PreparedStatement stm2 = conn.prepareStatement(sql,
            ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

    PreparedStatement stm3 = conn.prepareStatement("CREATE EVENT TestProdukt ON SCHEDULE AT '2015-02-15 15:15:00' DO UPDATE Auktion SET AvslutadAuktion = 1 WHERE produktnamn = TestProdukt",
            ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);


    stm.execute();
    System.out.println("Skapat Skiten");

    stm.close();
}
```

So i've gotten both "stm2" and "stm3" works, but for some reason when i try and use stm which uses the .setString it all goes fubar.

I've tried removing the stm.setString(2, slutdatum) in case it was moaning about it wanting a Date formated value instead of string but that didnt help. It seems fail the moment the ? gets introduced. So i'm wondering what i'm doing wrong, and if there is another workaround except for using the stm2 variant since i doubt it's SQL safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think event name cant set as parameter.Do

```
String eventName="myEventName";//set event name
PreparedStatement stm = conn.prepareStatement("CREATE EVENT "+eventName+" ON SCHEDULE AT ? DO UPDATE Auktion SET AvslutadAuktion = 1 WHERE produktnamn = ?",
```

> Always remember when you think you are having sql problem print the
>   query in console and copy the query and run it in your database gui
>   then you can check whats wrong with the query.

Comment: Yupp, that was it. The eventName cant be any variable apparently.